# get data when session id matches table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, reporting-services

I am trying to retrieve all reports from `report` when Session StaffID matches StaffID in `reports` table.

```
Report_Name, ReportDate and ReportID are part of the report table
```

**this is how i think it should go**

Get `ReportID`, `Report_Name` and `ReportDate` from `report` where `ReportID` from `Read_Report` matches `ReportID` from `report`
when session `StaffID`= `StaffID` in `Read_Report`

**and this is my query**

```
function get_read_report()
    {
        $this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
            ->from('Read_Report')
            ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
            ->where('StaffID', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
        return $result = $this->db->get();
    }
```

**I get this error**

> Error Number: 1066
>
> ```
> Not unique table/alias: 'Read_Report'
>
> SELECT `report`.`Report_Name`, `report`.`ReportDate`, `report`.`ReportID` FROM `Read_Report` JOIN `Read_Report` ON
> ```
>
> `report`.`ReportID` = `Read_Report`.`ReportID` WHERE `StaffID` = '3'
>
> ```
> Filename: models/report/Report_model.php
>
> Line Number: 91
> ```

**Controller code**

```
 function my_read_reports()
    {
        $data = array();

        if ($query = $this->report_model->get_read_report()) {
            $data['reports'] = $query;
        }

        $this->template['middle'] = $this->load->view($this->middle = 'pages/read_reports_view', $data, true);
        $this->layout();
    }
```

Comment: You just missed correct table at the time of joining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join your table with `report` table not the same table

Change

```
 ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
```

TO

```
 ->join('report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
```

You need to change your query to

```
$this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
            ->from('report')
            ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
            ->where('Read_Report.StaffID', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
         $result = $this->db->get();
         return $result->result();// fetch data then return
```

Comment: hmm getting Undefined property: mysqli::$ReportDate

Comment: `ReportDate` belong to which table??

Comment: reports table, same with Report_Name and ReportID

Comment: Have done, but still getting Undefined property, Il Pop my controller in the question

Comment: have posted some more info

Comment: I am not sure but are you missing to fetch data from your query??

Comment: If you miss the use `$result->result();` or you can check my updated answer

Comment: You to @saty. almost the weekend

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be

```
 $this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
        ->from('Read_Report')
        ->join('report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
        ->where('StaffID', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
        return $result = $this->db->get();
```